# Remove Duplicates from Activerecord has_many Call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following database schema model for a Jukebox:

```
Artist
  has_many :albums
  has_many :tracks, through: :albums
Album
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :tracks
Track
  belongs_to :album
  has_one :artist, through: :album
  belongs_to :genre
Genre
  has_many :tracks
  has_many :albums, through: :tracks
  has_many :artists, through: :albums
```

I want to be able to call `.albums` on an instance of the `Genre` class and `return` an array with one instance of each of the albums that has tracks with the associated `genre_id`.

What I'm getting is an array with duplicates of the same album instance for each track.  E.G. if there are 10,000 tracks with the `genre_id` associated to "Rock", I'm going to get an array with 10,000 instances when calling `.album`, even if there's only 1000 unique albums within that array.

I'm trying to solve this for a challenge, so just running `.all.uniq` on the call won't be sufficient.  I need to have something inside the class itself that will return the desired result when `.all` is run.

However, I can't find the ActiveRecord command that would essentially filter out the duplicates, and trying to write a separate class method doesn't seem to work either.

Disclosure - I've only been working with ActiveRecord for a few days.  I hope the above is clear.  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`distinct`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-distinct) should work for you:

```
genre = Genre.first
genre.albums.distinct
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! Yes, I think that would work for just calling it.  Unfortunately, I'm trying to pass a test and the test specifically wants to run `genre.album.all` and get only the unique number of albums back.  It's a rake test that I can't amend, so I'd need to have the solution in the class itself, and I can't see how to implement that within it...

Comment: You can try adding `default_scope { distinct }` to the `Album` class. But that may lead to all kinds of weird side effects. I wonder why you cannot change the test when it obviously is doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh - I eventually found the answer, thanks to this article: https://www.lugolabs.com/articles/distinct-active-records-in-has_many-through-associations

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tracks
  has_many :albums, -> { distinct }, through: :tracks
  has_many :artists, -> { distinct }, through: :albums
end
```